# offlineAudioContext.oncomplete never fires after running startRendering() on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit, web-audio-api

The `oncomplete` event of the `webkitOfflineAudioContext` never fires after running the context's `startRendering()` method. Even with a fix for iOS's requirement of a touch event to initiate sound.

Example jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9kpdjk2y/16/

Note that running this fiddle in Chrome, Firefox etc will result in a success message being appended below the button. On iOS this event is never fired and so the renderedBuffer can never be accessed.

This is driving me crazy, am I overlooking something?

Tested on iPhone 6, iPhone 6s on iOS 9. Not tested on iOS 10 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the iOS version of WebAudio does not support the `oncomplete` event.  This is a relatively new addition to WebAudio.

Comment: Seems pretty crazy. Would that not render the offline context useless as you can't retrieve a buffer from it?

Comment: Oh, wait.  You're right. I was thinking of something else.  I don't know why. Sorry.  You should probably file a bug against Safari on iOS.  This should be working.